# How to use Either String (IO())

Tags: haskell, gif, juicy-pixels

I'm working with Juicy Pixels library in Haskell and i want to make a GIF animation with a list of **image PixelRGB8**. There's a function that do that (writeGifAnimation), but it returns a type that i don't know how to use (Either String (IO())).
Can anybody help me?

The way i'm using it:
`writeGifAnimation "test.gif" 1 LoopingForever image_list`

The error: `Couldn't match expected type ‘IO ()’ with actual type ‘Either String (IO ())’`

The library documentation:
[https://hackage.haskell.org/package/JuicyPixels-3.3.7/docs/Codec-Picture.html#v:savePngImage:~:text=the%20same%20delay.-,writeGifAnimation,-%3A%3A%20FilePath%20%2D%3E](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/JuicyPixels-3.3.7/docs/Codec-Picture.html#v:savePngImage:%7E:text=the%20same%20delay.-,writeGifAnimation,-%3A%3A%20FilePath%20%2D%3E)

Answer (score 3):

You should check whether it is a `Left s` with `s` an error, or a `Right i` with `i` an `IO ()` action, so:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    -- …
    case writeGifAnimation "test.gif" 1 LoopingForever image_list of
        Left s -> fail s
        Right i -> i
    -- …
```